# Convert byte slice to io.Reader

Tags: go

In my project, I have a byte slice from a request's response.

```
defer resp.Body.Close()
if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
    log.Println("StatusCode为" + strconv.Itoa(resp.StatusCode))
    return
}

respByte, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
log.Println("fail to read response data")
    return
}
```

This works, but if I want to get the response's body for `io.Reader`, how do I convert? I tried the newreader/writer but wasn't successful.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want the response as `io.Reader`? In that case resp.Body is already of that type.

Comment: http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewReader will "turn" a `[]byte` to an `io.Reader` (and io.ReadSeeker)

Comment: @Arjan yap~body...i want get the response as io.reader  .but in the base class when i finish the request,the response have been killed.. just save a response body as []byte in struct.

Comment: @ANisus  i will try....thx dude..by the way...it's look's like different type..

Comment: @ChanWillson: That requirement makes more sense, the body cannot be read after closing it. As suggested use `*bytes.Reader` which implements the `io.Reader` interface.

Comment: @ChanWillson It is a different type. One is an interface, the other a value that implements that interface. I created an answer from my comment, trying to explain it a bit.

Answer (score 482):

To get a type that implements `io.Reader` from a `[]byte` slice, you can use [`bytes.NewReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewReader) in the [`bytes`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes) package:

```
r := bytes.NewReader(byteData)
```

This will return a value of type [`bytes.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Reader) which implements the [`io.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader) (and [`io.ReadSeeker`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadSeeker)) interface.

Don't worry about them not being the same "type". `io.Reader` is an interface and can be implemented by many different types. To learn a little bit more about interfaces in Go, read [Effective Go: Interfaces and Types](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces_and_types).

Comment: Is there a similar function to turn a `[]byte` into an `io.Writer`? E.g. `bytes.NewWriter(destination)`

Comment: @byxor Yes, what you are looking for is [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer). There you create a buffer that implements `io.Writer` like this: `w := bytes.NewBuffer(destination)`.

Comment: I do not understand this error from `govet`: `cannot use *bytes.NewReader(out.Bytes()) (type bytes.Reader) as type io.Reader in argument to ioutil.NopCloser` :(

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich That is because `bytes.Reader` has pointer receivers, and you are turning it from a pointer type (`*bytes.Reader`) to a base type (`bytes.Reader`) . Just get rid of the asterisk (`*`) and you should be fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a buffer also works:

```
r := bytes.NewBuffer(byteData)
```

Comment: Have you seen the older answer from 2015? Does the new answer bring anything new?